# Is this the correct way for connecting database (.mdf file) to visual studio project?

Tags: c#

for this i am not getting any output thought there is not any error or warning... i guess the problem is with connection string but not sure, is it?? i have created a database name RV(.mdf file) in SQL server data tool and connected it to this project in visual studio.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace student_TableConnectTry1
{



    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection())
            {


                    cn.ConnectionString =@"Data Source=(local);Integrated Security=SSPI;" +"Initial Catalog=RV";

                cn.Open();



                string strSQL = "Select * From student";
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, cn);
                using (SqlDataReader myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    // Loop over the results.
                    while (myDataReader.Read())
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("-> usn: {0}, name: {1}.",
                        myDataReader["usn"].ToString(),
                        myDataReader["name"].ToString()
                        );
                    }
                }

                Console.ReadLine();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any data in the `student` table?

Comment: keep the break point & check also use try catch blocks to handle the exception

Comment: @unlimit yes i do have.

Comment: @vijay i tried that couldn't find any exception there

Comment: does the myDataReader have any values?code seems fine for me.

Comment: @vijay  no, this code simply prints all the data values stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following connection string and try:

```
Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=youruserid;Initial Catalog=databasename;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS
```

Also see the following link for connectionstring:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

I hope it will help you. :)

Let me know if it does not help you.

Comment: nope still the result is same... i guess problem is with 
Data Source=(local)
is that correct?

Comment: The proper connection string is given in the web page you linked.  Use the "Attach a database file on connect to a local SQL Server Express instance" example.

Comment: @HansPassant  hey i didn't get you... where exactly you are pointing at?

Comment: If you are referring to local machine, then you can put '.' as local current machine and check whether you have instance name for that db.?